# Ajax added HTML doesn't inherit page styles - jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, dom, jquery-mobile

So I'm fairly new to jQueryMobile but I've managed to create a search bar that displays results as you're typing using Ajax that's working just fine but the problem is that CSS Styles aren't being applied to the ajax'd content.

Is there a way I can force the CSS to either refresh or recache or just have the CSS apply to the newly ajax'd html?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the content added by AJAX should still be styled. Can you add the relative CSS/HTML/JQuery so we can have a look at it in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Enhancing new markup**
>  The page plugin dispatches a pagecreate event, which most widgets use to auto-initialize themselves. As long
>   as a widget plugin script is referenced, it will automatically enhance
>   any instances of the widgets it finds on the page.
>
> However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via
>   Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
>   handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
>   the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
>   div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
>   (listview button, select, etc.).
>
> For example, if a block of HTML markup (say a login form) was loaded
>   in through Ajax, trigger the create event to automatically transform
>   all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this case) into the
>   enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:
>
> ```
> $( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
> ```
>
> **Create vs. refresh: An important distinction**
>  Note that there is an important difference between the create event and refresh method
>   that some widgets have. The create event is suited for enhancing raw
>   markup that contains one or more widgets. The refresh method should be
>   used on existing (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated
>   programmatically and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with `data-role=listview` attribute after page
>   creation, triggering create on a parent element of that list would
>   transform it into a listview styled widget. If more list items were
>   then programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method
>   would update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave
>   the existing list items untouched.

jQM Docs here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> **Refreshing form elements**
>  In jQuery Mobile, some enhanced form controls are simply styled (inputs), but others are custom
>   controls (selects, sliders) built from, and kept in sync with, the
>   native control. To programmatically update a form control with
>   JavaScript, first manipulate the native control, then use the refresh
>   method to tell the enhanced control to update itself to match the new
>   state. Here are some examples of how to update common form controls,
>   then call the refresh method:

Checkboxes:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Radios:

```
$("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Selects:

```
var myselect = $("#selectfoo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Sliders:

```
$("input[type='range']").val(60).slider("refresh");
```

Flip switches (they use slider):

```
var myswitch = $("#selectbar");
myswitch[0].selectedIndex = 1;
myswitch.slider("refresh");
```

jQM Docs here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

Comment: Found the solution: $('#search_preview ul').listview();